# AVCaptureDevice isFlashModeSupported deprecated iOS 10

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios10, avcapture

I am using AVCaptureDevice's instance method "isFlashModeSupported" as below:

```
NSArray *captureDeviceType = @[AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera,AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInMicrophone];
AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession *captureDevice = [AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession discoverySessionWithDeviceTypes:captureDeviceType mediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo position:AVCaptureDevicePositionUnspecified];

NSArray *deviceList = [captureDevice devices];
AVCaptureDevice *selectedCamera = [deviceList objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)currentCameraDeviceIndex];

if ( [selectedCamera isFlashModeSupported:AVCaptureFlashModeAuto] ){
        [selectedCamera setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeAuto];   // AVCaptureFlashModeAuto
    }
```

But in iOS 10 `isFlashModeSupported` and `setFlashMode` methods are deprecated.

Xcode suggest to use AVCapturePhotoOutput's -supportedFlashModes instead.

Is any idea how to use the above method?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. This works perfectly.

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
[session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];


AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
if ([device hasFlash]) {
   [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
   device.flashMode = AVCaptureFlashModeAuto;
   [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

Comment: You are checking device has flash or not. But I want to check supported flash mode like isFlashModeSupported. Also flashMode property is deprecated. Xcode suggesting to use AVCapturePhotoOutput's -supportedFlashModes instead.

Answer (score 0):

How is it with this?

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

if ([device hasFlash]) {
    if ([self.stillImageOutput.supportedFlashModes containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVCaptureFlashModeOn]]) {


}
```

Comment: The "self" in the 2nd if condition in the answer is not clear.