# 'isFlashModeSupported:' is deprecated: Is there a new method to 'setFlashMode'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avfoundation

I have this code, first written a few years ago now. The following code embodies the warnings I'm getting and I can't seem to find the new method of implementing such a simple bit of code. I've been trying all sorts of things suggested by Apple Resources to no avail. This code still works, with warnings, but I suspect will soon not work at all. Is there a new method to 'setFlashMode'?

> **'isFlashModeSupported:' is deprecated:** and 
>   **'setFlashMode:' is deprecated:**

```
+ (void)setFlashMode:(AVCaptureFlashMode)flashMode forDevice:(AVCaptureDevice *)device
{

    if ([device hasFlash] && [device isFlashModeSupported:flashMode])
        {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error])
        {
            [device setFlashMode:flashMode];
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
    }
}
```

If I use from example 1 in Other Answer,

> device.flashMode = AVCaptureFlashModeAuto;  ...... 'flashMode' is
>   deprecated:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AVCaptureDevice isFlashModeSupported deprecated iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135071/avcapturedevice-isflashmodesupported-deprecated-ios-10)

Comment: Sorry, it's not quite the same. I'm spending just as much time on this aas the original.

Answer (score -1):

assign it directly..

`device.flashMode = AVCaptureFlashModeAuto;`

Comment: device.flashMode = AVCaptureFlashModeAuto; ......'flashMode' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use AVCapturePhotoSettings.flashMode instead.